# How to calculate the sum of values using PySpark with Kafka and Spark Streaming

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, addition, spark-streaming-kafka

Currently I receive 4 or more vehicle IoT sensory data records every 1 second, and I would like to for just simplicity sakes start by adding the 4 values for velocity readings. Most of the examples of code I have found provide counts which I can already do, but how would I simply add 4 or more separate lines of velocity values. Right now, the output shows a 1 second time stamp with 4x extracted velocity values.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("rjws-sparkstreams")

#Pauses for Context Load
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, '172.16.10.1:2181', 'spark-streaming', {'vehicle_events':1})



#Presents JSON formatted data
KafkaStream_json = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))

#Parses the Velocity column of data
velocity_dstream = KafkaStream_json.map(lambda vehicle_events_fast_testdata: vehicle_events_fast_testdata["velocity"])
velocity_readings = velocity_dstream.countByValue()
top_reads = velocity_readings.transform(lambda rdd:sc.parallelize(rdd.take(50)))

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I have attempted adding the following code too:

```
total = 0
def velParse(vehicle_events_fast_testdata):
    total = sum(vehicle_events_fast_testdata["velocity"]) + (total)
    return vehicle_events_fast_testdata["velocity"]

velocity_dstream = KafkaStream_json.map(lambda vehicle_events_fast_testdata: velParse(vehicle_events_fast_testdata))
```

However this does not properly calculate the sum of the velocity readings, it states the item is not iterable.  Thanks